# python script not running from cron

Tags: python, mongodb, cron

It runs by hand when I execute:

```
python /var/lib/mongodb/script.py >> /var/lib/mongodb/script.log 2>&1
```

But using cronjob, I see that script is executed but no output in /var/lib/mongodb/script.log

```
sudo -u mongodb crontab -l
* * * * * python /var/lib/mongodb/script.py >> /var/lib/mongodb/script.log 2>&1
```

on /var/log/syslog I see that cron is executed but no output in /var/lib/mongodb/script.log and the script.py is not running.

**Update:**

I tried with a test.py script and is working:

`root@jessie:~# ls -al /var/lib/mongodb/test.py 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 184 May 10 13:49 /var/lib/mongodb/test.py`

`root@jessie:~# sudo -u mongodb crontab -e
* * * * * python  /var/lib/mongodb/test.py >> /var/lib/mongodb/test.log 2>&1`

`May 10 14:02:01 jessie CRON[1889]: (mongodb) CMD (python  /var/lib/mongodb/test.py >> /var/lib/mongodb/test.log 2>&1)`

`root@jessie:~# ls -al /var/lib/mongodb/test.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 mongodb nogroup 1792 May 10 14:04 /var/lib/mongodb/test.log`

The test.py script contains:

`print "Hello World!"
print "Hello Again"
print "I like typing this."
print "This is fun."
print 'Yay! Printing.'`

Comment: does user `mongodb` has write permissions on `/var/lib/mongodb/script.log` file?

Comment: yes, 
drwxr-xr-x  2 mongodb mongodb 4096 May  8 14:20 mongodb

Comment: what about setting the full path to python (i.e. `/usr/bin/python`)?

Comment: I tried that also, same behaviour. It runs by hand, but does't run from cron

Comment: when you say by hand, I assume you're running it as `mongodb` user, right? What about your `/etc/cron.allow` or `/etc/cron.deny` files?

Comment: Yes, by hand means:

su -c "python /var/lib/mongodb/script.py >> /var/lib/mongodb/script.log 2>&1" -s /bin/sh mongodb
`/etc/cron.allow` and `/etc/cron.deny` don't exists

Answer (score 0):

**Your `.py` file is not executable; use `chmod +x` and try to run cron job again.**

Similar case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62190127/setting-up-a-cronjob-on-google-compute-engine/62192532#62192532). Making file executable helped.